# $scope doesn't reflect ng-model

Tags: angularjs

The ng-model defined in a select-tag does not seem to affect the controller $scope-variable with the same name.

Controller:

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope, $state, User, apiUrls) {
  $scope.enviroments = apiUrls;
  $scope.updateEnviroment = function() {
    console.log($scope.selectedEnv);
  }
})
```

View:

```
 <label class="item item-input item-select">
  <div class="input-label">
    Enviroment
  </div>
    <select ng-model="selectedEnv" ng-options="item as item.name for item in enviroments" ng-change="updateEnviroment()" ng-init="selectedEnv = enviroments[0]">
  </select>
</label>  
<p>{{selectedEnv}}</p>
```

And for clearity, the constant:

```
myApp.constant('apiUrls', [
  { "name": 'Production', "id": 1, "url": 'http://api.server.com/api/v1' },
  { "name": 'Developement', "id": 2, "url": 'http://apidev.server.com/api/v1' },
  { "name": 'Local', "id": 3, "url": 'http://localhost/CABApi/api/v1'}
  ]
);
```

console.log($scope.selectedEnv); => undefined (?)

Obviously something is not correct that I'm failing to recognize, any ideas?

Comment: you must have missing something silly http://plnkr.co/edit/9CmXbMfNoQGNoWzeKDax?p=preview could you please reproduce issue here

Comment: working fine here http://jsbin.com/macuvuwaxa/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: To clearify, <p>{{selectedEnv}}</p> does display the currently selected enviroment, however the console.log($scope.selectedEnv) is always undefined.

Comment: @SigurdBøasæter why you don't reproduce this issue here in plunkr or codepen

Comment: @pankajparkar So far i have not been able to reproduce it.

Comment: If i change the view to ng-change="updateEnviroment(selectedEnv)", and the method to:   $scope.updateEnviroment = function(newSelectedEnv) { console.log(newSelectedEnv);    console.log($scope.selectedEnv);  } , it will log the correct item and an undefined. (This is in an Ionic-app, if that influences anything)

Comment: Your select must be inside a directive which defines its own scope, like ng-if or ng-repeat. Always have a dot in your ng-model. Always initialize the object containing the model values in the controller: `$scope.model = {}`; `ng-model="model.selectedEnv"`

Comment: As already noted about dot in `ng-model` this sounds like a classic case of trying to 2 way bind a primitive in child scope

Comment: @JBNizet I wish i could give you rep or something, i was almost declared insane, Thank you!

Comment: @SigurdBøasæter you're welcome. Glad to help you keep sane.